# Caching images in another thread before user sees it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, caching

I'm working on a eBook program in WPF recently, and the pages of the book are all saved as `.jpg` format. Since the images are all in high quality, the program will lag while switching pages.

I tried to cache a few images after the current image which the user is seeing in another thread. But it gives me an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

I can fix the error by adding `Invoke`, but the performance is like without the memory cache.

But without `Invoke`, the programs shows the error above. And I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to make the code as simple as I could.

Any help is appreciated.

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Caching;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ThreadedMemoryCache_Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MemoryCache memcache;
        int num = 0;
        Image img;
        int BufferPages = 2;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Change Content
            img = new Image();
            Content = img;
            //Mouse Events
            MouseDown += (s, e) =>
            {
                int add = 0;
                if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                    add--;
                else if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
                    add++;
                else
                    return;
                num += add;
                img.Source = GetBitmap(num);  //Error here
                Buffer();
            };
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Initiallize MemoryCache
            NameValueCollection CacheSettings = new NameValueCollection(3);
            CacheSettings.Add("CacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", Convert.ToString(1));
            CacheSettings.Add("physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", Convert.ToString(10));
            CacheSettings.Add("pollingInterval", Convert.ToString("00:00:10"));
            memcache = new MemoryCache("BitmapCache", CacheSettings);
            //Get First Photo
            img.Source = GetBitmap(num);
            Buffer();
        }
        BitmapImage GetBitmap(int num)
        {
            String id = num.ToString();
            BitmapImage cachebmp = memcache[id] as BitmapImage;
            if (cachebmp == null)
            {
                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                String name = num.ToString() + ".jpg";
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(name);
                if(!file.Exists)
                {
                    num = 0;
                    return GetBitmap(num);
                }
                cachebmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.FullName));
                memcache.Set(id, cachebmp, policy);
            }
            return cachebmp;
        }
        void Buffer()
        {
            //Start Thread
            Thread cachethread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= BufferPages; i++)
                {
                    //Adding invoke fixes the error, but it seems to delay the main thread and cause lag.
                    //this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    //{
                    GetBitmap(num + i);
                    //}));
                }
            });
            cachethread.IsBackground = true;
            cachethread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Generally try to avoid `xxx.Invoke()` as it 1) blocks the worker thread 2) Can lead to deadlock.  _"but it seems to delay the main thread"_ - yes that's because invoke merely does it magic by using the Windows message pump which ultimately must be processed by the UI thread - hence the freeze if processing is significant

Comment: @Micky But without using `xxx.Invoke()`, it causes the `System.InvalidOperationException` error.

Comment: Although the `memcache` is created on the main thread, `Buffer()` is creating the initial set of `cachebmp` instances in a background thread. By adding `Invoke` you are forcing _all_ of the activity to occur on the main thread.

Comment: @HABO I know how the `Invoke` works, so I'm trying to access the `Bitmap` in the main thread without `Invoke`. But it causes error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to freeze the BitmapImage to make it cross-thread accessible:

```
cachebmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.FullName));
cachebmp.Freeze();
memcache.Set(id, cachebmp, policy);
```

---

That said, your code could be improved in many ways. Better use a [`ThreadPool`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx) thread or a `BackgroundWorker` or a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.100).aspx) to perform the background task.

Besides that you shouldn't call `GetBitmap(num)` recursively with `num = 0` in case an image file doesn't exist. What happens if the `0.jpg` is also missing?

Comment: The `0.jpg` problem is because I tried to shorten my code, so this is just a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BackgroundWorker` class.

Load some initial images at startup in MainThread, then start `BackgroundWorker` for rest of images.

Useful links : [How to: Use a Background Worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx), [BackgroundWorker In Wpf](http://www.jeremybytes.com/downloads/backgroundworkerinwpf.pdf).

Comment: will try to make a solution for your needs.